# What is the builtin `:` used for in Bash?

Tags: bash

From Bash Reference Manual

> : (a colon)
>
> `: [arguments]`
>
> Do nothing beyond expanding arguments and performing redirections. The
>   return status is zero.

I wonder how to use this builtin command?

What is its used for? I am trying to improve my understandings about expansions and redirections, and hope it can be useful.

Does "expanding arguments" mean all kinds of word expansions?

How can I see the result from performing expansions and redirections? `: [arguments]` doesn't write anything to stdout.